# Limit Cores Used By Ninja on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, ninja

I'm trying to limit the number of cores used by Ninja (1.10.0). I've been using the argument recommended when using CMake (3.11 and 3.18)

```
 '-DCMAKE_JOB_POOLS:STRING=compile=4;link=3'
```

Taken from

- https://discourse.slicer.org/t/ninja-build-using-too-many-cores/2304

However this seems to have no effect and the system still uses all available cores for the compiler (TASKING C compiler - cctc) with way more than 4 processes being started and running.

1. Is there some setting in the Ninja file that should be created to limit the compiler threads?
2. Is there anything special (like formatting) I need to do to make this work on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you run CMake in build tool mode to build an already-generated project binary tree, you can add additional arguments to the native build tool (Ninja in your case), e.g.

```
cmake --build builddir --target all --config Release -- -j4
```

See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) for CMake build tool mode and `ninja --help` for supported ninja command line options

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work for us. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the TASKING compiler not respecting the Ninja job limit, but I don't really know how to check that either....

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how the TASKING compiler handles that. Never used it before. I checked with a local build tree, Ninja, and Microsoft compilers.

Comment: Out of interest I've found that Gnu make 3.8 that's widely available doesn't allow limitation of jobs on Windows, so it either runs single jobs or as many as possible with -j option.
Compiling GnuMake 4.3 for Windows and I can control the number of jobs as required with for example -j 3 when calling the build.